# VueJS as SPA and jwt token, when to verify token

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Ive made an spa using vuejs and laravel, I have a login route and when the user submits successfully a token is saved on the localstorage, for further protected routes should I use an ajax request on before each route to ensure the token is valid?

Comment: No, you should attach the token in a header and check if it's valid with middleware on the server. No need to make an additional request for that.

Comment: As @devk, mentioned, middleware is fine, you can attach middleware to route path, or to put it directly in controller either in __construct()  method to have it for all routes related with specific controller, or in specific method

Comment: @niklaz So when navigating between routes for example /profile to /posts, do I only check that the token exists and the auth in the vuex state is set to true?